# Prove $\sum_{r=0}^n (r-1)r {n \choose r} = n(n-1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove the following binomial identity:

$\sum_{r=0}^n (r-1)r {n \choose r} = n(n-1)2^{n-2}$

Any direction or hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Start with
$$ (1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n{n\choose r}x^r$$
then differentiate twice, and then set $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have a group of $n$ people, and you want to form a club consisting of some subset of them. The club also has a president and a vice-president. The right-hand side counts the number of ways to first pick the president, then the vice-president, then a subset of the remaining $n-2$ people to be "normal members" of the club. Can you explain why the left side counts the same quantity?

Answer (score 2):

It is always the same trick that comes into place.

Introduce $f\colon x\mapsto (1+x)^n$ and look at its second derivative at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Let $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,1/2)$. Then
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n r(r-1) {n \choose r} \frac{1}{2^n}=EX(X-1)=EX^2-EX=\text{Var}X+(EX)^2-EX\tag{1}.
$$
But since $X=\sum_{1}^nY_i$ where the $Y_i$ are i.i.d $\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ random variables, it follows that
$$
EX=n/2;\quad \text{Var}X=n/4.\tag{2}
$$
Hence by (1) and (2),
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n r(r-1) {n \choose r} \frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{n(n-1)}{4}\implies
\sum_{r=0}^n r(r-1) {n \choose r}= n(n-1)2^{n-2}.\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=0}^n (r-1)(r) {n \choose r}$$
$$=n. \sum_{r=1}^n (r-1){n-1 \choose r-1}$$
$$=n(n-1). \sum_{r=2}^n {n-2 \choose r-2}$$
$$=n(n-1).2^{n-2}$$

As simple as that